# Loopback remote method that returns a file

Tags: json, loopbackjs, loopback

I am trying to write a Loopback remote method that will return my model's json configuration file "property.json" from this directory:

[image]

Currently what I am trying is that:

```
Sync.getSDKData = function(cb){

console.log("getSDKData called!");


 cb(null, "../common/models/property.json");
}

Sync.remoteMethod (
'getSDKData',
{
  http: {path: '/getSDKData', verb: 'get'},
  accepts: { },
  returns: {
    arg: 'data',
    type: 'object',
    root: true
  }
}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code is literally just returning a string. You want to use the fs package to read in the file contents and then return that instead.